# Terraform Remote S3 File Upload

Tags: terraform, github-actions, terraform-cloud

I'm moving my terraform apply into a GH Action. I'm following [this guide](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/github-actions#aws_access_key_id) for setting up the GH Action. I've created the terraform HCL, but now my Lambda Layers cannot be uploaded to the S3 bucket. How do I get the files to the remote terraform?

```
# main.tf
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "3.28.0"
    }
  }
  required_version = "~> 0.14"

  backend "remote" {
    organization = "tnorlund"

    workspaces {
      name = "gh-actions-demo"
    }
  }
}
...
module "python_layer" {
  source      = "./LambdaLayer"
  type        = "python"
  path        = ".."
  developer   = "Tyler Norlund"
  bucket_name = module.layer_bucket.bucket_name
  stage       = var.stage
}
...
```

```
#LambdaLayer/main.tf
# Adds a NodeJS or Python Lambda Layer

# Upload the compressed code to the S3 bucket
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "object" {
  bucket = var.bucket_name
  key    = var.type == "nodejs" ? "nodejs.zip" : "python.zip"
  source = var.type == "nodejs" ? "${var.path}/nodejs.zip" : "${var.path}/python.zip"
  etag   = var.type == "nodejs" ? filemd5("${var.path}/nodejs.zip") : filemd5("${var.path}/python.zip")
  tags = {
    Project   = "Blog"
    Stage     = var.stage
    Developer = var.developer
  }
}

# Use the uploaded code as the Lambda Layer's code
resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "layer" {
  layer_name = var.type == "nodejs" ? "analytics_js" : "analytics_python"
  s3_bucket = var.bucket_name
  s3_key = aws_s3_bucket_object.object.key

  description = var.type == "nodejs" ? "Node Framework used to access DynamoDB" : "Python Framework used to access DynamoDB"
  compatible_runtimes = var.type == "nodejs" ? ["nodejs12.x"] : ["python3.8"]
  source_code_hash = var.type == "nodejs" ? filebase64sha256("${var.path}/nodejs.zip") : filebase64sha256("${var.path}/python.zip")
}
```

Comment: Are you saying the `nodejs.zip` or `python.zip` files aren't available to the GitHub action? Any reason you can't create those and then pass them with `upload-artifact` and `download-artifact`?

Comment: So this is what I was doing locally. TF Cloud runs the apply remotely, meaning that the files aren't there. TF Cloud only has access to the '.tf' files. I'm currently refactoring this so that the AWS resources access S3 objects rather than the local files.